# Viewing the SQL query that created the database?

Tags: mariadb

How can I view the text input query that was used to create a database table?
I'm using MariaDB with PHPMyAdmin!

Edit: I remember I found it long ago, when clicking on edit or change or something similar! Damn it's not easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the documentation is your friend:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-create-database/

Answer (score 0):

Most things can se seen with [SHOW](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-create-database/)

```
Show create database testdb
```